# calculate x years for savings with deposition and revenue C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, int, double

I'm sitting with a challenging homework in C++ and would be really thankful for some help here!

My program need to calculate how many years it will take for an optional yearly deposition with revenue to reach a specific savings limit.

I just can't see what's wrong and have tried debugging with no help.
It doesn't really help neither that i'm totally new to C++ and MVS 2015.

I don't know if it's the math or the programming itself that is wrong.
Static typing is foreign to me since I usually use python.

Also VS don't give much information and the program just stops after asking for revenue input.

Any suggestions?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int deposit;
    int max_savings;
    double revenue;
    double change_factor;
    double year = 0;
    double geometric_sum;

    cout << "Choose a yearly deposition:\n";
    cin >> deposit;
    cout << "Set your max saving-goal:\n";
    cin >> max_savings;
    cout << "set a revenue in percent:\n";
    cin >> revenue;

    change_factor = 1 + (revenue / 100);
    geometric_sum = ((double)deposit * (pow(change_factor, year) - 1)) / (change_factor - 1);

    while (geometric_sum < max_savings)
        year++;

    cout << "Your saving-goal will be in " << year << " years!" << endl;
    cout << "Your account balance will then be " << geometric_sum << " dollars!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should describe what happens when you try to compile and run the program. What is the program output?

Comment: Look at that `while` loop condition. Look at the code *in* the loop. Now ask yourself this: What, in the only statement in the actual while-loop body, could possibly change that condition from `true` to `false`? **Neither** `geometric_sum` nor `max_savings` are changed in any way, so if that condition is initially true, it will **always** be true, and your loop will spin infinitely. Therefore, you never reach the output statements, and your program never ends. And fyi, single-stepping a debugger would have made this immediately apparent, so "have tried debugging" is rather hard to believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pow(change_factor, year) - 1`

`year` is set to 0. Any value at the power of 0 is 1. `1 - 1 = 0`. Basically you are multiplying with 0.

Comment: yeah but i increment year with 1 so long the loop is true which it is.

Comment: @DanielBäck And where do you recalculate the `geometric_sum`?

Comment: @DanielBäck `while (geometric_sum < max_savings)` this is and endless loop, your `geometric_sum` will stay 0 till the end of the time.

Comment: can i just put the geometric_sum in the while loop after year++;?

Comment: @DanielBäck Yes: `while (geometric_sum < max_savings) { year++; geometric_sum = ((double)deposit * (pow(change_factor, year) - 1)) / (change_factor - 1); }` Also I suggest reading about functions (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_functions.htm) and about flow control (http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/). These are very basic stuff and you should understand them.